# Script to reformat command output line-by-line

Tags: bash

I have a program which outputs a pair of words surrounded by spaces on each output line:

```
  aa  bb
  ccc ddd
  ee  fff
```

I would like to reformat those in a bash script to remove the spaces and separate the words with a '/'

```
aa/bb 
ccc/ddd
ee/fff`
```

So far the only way I've figured out is two scripts:

script1:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
  ./script2 $line
done
```

script2:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $1/$2
```

Is there some obvious way to do it in one script that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read a b 
do 
    echo "$a/$b" 
done
```

Comment: Hunh,  I never realized read could take multiple variables.  Good answer

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{print $1 "/" $2}' inputfilename.txt
```